# shared memory segment shmget shmat double access both

Tags: c, struct, shared-memory

I need some help with this code.

I created, in a shared segment, a `struct msg_t`,  and in another segment, I created a simple `string`.
In this method, first I attach both segments and then I want to initialize the string.
then I try to write into a field of my `struct msg_t` (in my first segment) a pointer to that string(allocated in the second segment). I did many tests, but it seems that when I try to print the content of that field accessing from the first segment it prints "".

How can I do this ?? Thank you for your help.

```
msg_t* msg_init_string(void* content) {
    //viene creata una copia "privata" della stringa
    msg_t* new_msg;
    int new_msg_id;
    int content_id;
    char* string = (char*) content;
    if ((new_msg_id = shmget(ftok(FILENAME2,'N'),sizeof(msg_t),IPC_CREAT|0666)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget() for array_msg");

        exit(-1);
    }
    if ((content_id = shmget(ftok(FILENAME2,'C'),(strlen(string) + 1),IPC_CREAT|0666)) == -1) {
        perror("shmget() for array_msg");

        exit(-1);
    }
    new_msg = (msg_t*)shmat(new_msg_id, NULL,0);

    char* new_content =(char*)shmat(content_id,NULL,0);// +1 per \0 finale
    strcpy(new_content, string);
    printf("here \n %s",(char*)(new_content));


//here it seems not working..because then, it can not print anything!!
    new_msg->content =new_content;

    printf("here \n %s",(char*)(new_msg->content));



    return new_msg;
```

my simple `struct msg_t` is:

```
typedef struct msg {

void* content; // generico contenuto del messaggio

struct msg * (*msg_init)(void*); // creazione msg

void (*msg_destroy)(struct msg *); // deallocazione msg

struct msg * (*msg_copy)(struct msg *); // creazione/copia msg

} msg_t;
```

Comment: Always try to post a compilable runnable program, rather than fragments one must finish by hand and assemble.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you just don't see what the second `printf()` prints for `%s` because the output is *line buffered* and shows only after another `\n` is put to `stdout`. Better end a format string with `\n` whenever feasible.